# web3.utils.toWei(web3.utils.fromWei(...))

Tags: web3js, bignumber

Is it warranted that `web3.utils.toWei(web3.utils.fromWei(x))` is equal in numeric value to `x` (provided that `x` is a 256 bit number represented as a string)?

If it is not warranted, how to obtain a value not less (maybe a *little* greater) that `x` knowing `web3.utils.fromWei(x)`?

Answer (score 0):

The experiment (takes like 15 sec on my i5 processor)

```js
for(let i=0; i<1000000; ++i) {
  x = web3.utils.randomHex(32);
  if(x.replace(/x0*/, "x") !=  web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(web3.utils.fromWei(x)))) {
    console.log(x);
    break;
  }
}
```

shows that in this case rounding errors do not happen.